# LOGO AND FAVICON ICON CHANGE MAGENTO 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, logo

I tried to change luma logo and Magento favicon icon in Magento Ver 2.2.4, it refused and keeps saying **Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set**....

Please any simple solution to this am not a developer

Answer (score 0):

This is [magento 2.2.4 know issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968).The themes' changes you made work for global and website level  but not the store view level. You should wait for the fix or try to use magento 2.2.3 it's a stable version.

Comment: looking for the clean link to get the magento 2.2.3     Any help please

Comment: Hey , you Can download Magento 2.2.3 from here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download . Go go release archive ans u Can find thé version 2.2.3

Comment: Thanks, how do i create a banner in 2.2.4, cant seem to find the banner tab

Comment: this link can help you https://www.cloudways.com/blog/customize-homepage-of-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem in v 2.2.4 and have quick fix for this.

you need to add `di.xml` in adminhtml area in you custom module.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="area" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

hope its will work for you.